# Facebook Graph API: how do I delete a status message (of mine)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've written a small facebook client app which can post and retrieve status messages.

Now I want to be able to delete this status messages I have posted. I tried to achieve this by opening the following URL:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/" + postID + "?method=delete&access_token=" + AccessToken;
```

If I do this I get an error message 403 (invalid).

I can delete a status message, if it was posted by my program. But I can't delete it if it was posted by some other program. But this is what I need to do :(

Do I need special rights to remove a status message? Which? Or do I need to use another call to remove it?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to delete objects in the Graph API that were created by other Applications. All part of the permissions sandboxing in Facebook I assume.

Although, I'd love to be proved wrong.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but that looks like it should work. Do you have `stream_publish` permissions?

Comment: Yes. I can publish, and I can delete the things I published with my app, but I can't delete posts published by others apps.

Answer (score 1):

I think i'm late with my answer, but i hope someone can still use it. But i think you have to prepend your userid to the ID of the status message you want to delete.

Like this: https://graph.facebook.com/64568227_27863456432483453?access_token={access_token} where 64568227 is the userID and 27863456432483453 is the status message id.

Comment: I tried (the userid is contained in my postid) but I still get an error 403. It seems facebook denieds deletion of stuff :(